# After calling finish(); of current activity, it will remain in BackStack or not?

Tags: android, android-activity, back-stack

I am new to Android.

I have 2 Activity. A and B. A is my launcher Activity. 
Now in A activity, I am calling B Activity and also finishing A activity.

Something like this,

```
Intent ib=new Intent(this,B.class);
      startActivity(ib);
      this.finish();
```

So, When B Activity will be active, A will remain in backstack or not? And I am using default launch mode.

Thank you in advance.

Edit  :::

ok, Thank you.

Now I have one question,

I am calling 3 activities in this order A->B->C.

When I am Calling another activity, I am finishing current activity.
by using,

this.finish();

I am also putting log for back stack in C Activity.
Here is my backstack printing code::

```
ActivityManager m = (ActivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> runningTaskInfoList = m.getRunningTasks(10);
        Iterator<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> itr = runningTaskInfoList.iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo runningTaskInfo = (ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo) itr.next();
            int id = runningTaskInfo.id;
            CharSequence desc = runningTaskInfo.description;
            int numOfActivities = runningTaskInfo.numActivities;
            String topActivity = runningTaskInfo.topActivity
                    .getShortClassName();

            Log.d("runningTaskInfoSize",runningTaskInfoList.size()+"");

            Log.d("Stack :: ","C Start --------------------->");
            Log.d("Stack ID ::",id+"");
            Log.d("Stack NumOfActivity ::",numOfActivities+"");
            Log.d("Stack Top Activity ::",topActivity+"");
        }
```

Now, in log, I am getting this when C is Visible:

```
D/Stack ::: C Start --------------------->
D/Stack ID ::: 29
D/Stack Desc ::: null
D/Stack NumOfActivity ::: 2
D/Stack Top Activity ::: .C
D/Stack ::: C Start --------------------->
D/Stack ID ::: 1
D/Stack Desc ::: null
D/Stack NumOfActivity ::: 1
D/Stack Top Activity ::: com.android.launcher2.Launcher
```

If Activity will not remain in backstack after finish, Then why i am getting **'NumOfActivity ::: 2'** ?? or Is there something wrong with my code or understanding?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack.html

Comment: what's your exact problem?

Comment: I want to know, If after finish(); ,Activity won't remain in back stack, Then Why It is showing no of Activity=2?, As i asked above.

Comment: add in your question the code you use to start each activity (the full method of activities A and B)

Comment: in which method you put your log code?

Comment: inside onCreate() method

Comment: All Activity calling, however, name changes,                                          Intent ib=new Intent(this,B.class);
startActivity(ib);
this.finish();

Comment: check my updated answer ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the `Activity A` will not remain in the backstack if you call `finish()`.
[Here you can find the official documentation about it](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html).

Using`finish()`, it will call `onPause()`, `onStop()` and `onDestroy()` in this order.

For any further information just ask, hope this help

## Edit

The problem is in the method call order: from [official Doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/index.html)

> The order of lifecycle callbacks is well defined, particularly when
>   the two activities are in the same process and one is starting the
>   other. Here's the order of operations that occur when Activity A
>   starts Acivity B:
>
> Activity A's onPause() method executes. Activity B's onCreate(),
>   onStart(), and onResume() methods execute in sequence. (Activity B now
>   has user focus.) Then, if Activity A is no longer visible on screen,
>   its onStop() method executes.

So, as you can see, the problem is that you check the Activity count in `Activity C` before `Activity B` is stopped.

## LifeCycle of activity:

[image]

Comment: So, When should i check back stack, i mean in which method?

Comment: @zephyr if you explain what you need it for, I can help more.. said like this looks a bit useless to do, and also tricky. You probably should create an interface for it. Try explain what you need to do with that information and maybe there are easier way for it :)

Comment: Well, I am learning activity launch modes, So I need backStack Log for it. otherwise How will I know about singleTop or singleTask launch happened or not?

Comment: @zephyr assume (from official documentation) that after "onDestroy()" method the activity doesn't exists anymore. Now put a log in onResume(), onPause(), onStop(), onCreate(), ... methods. your log will teach you how it works. I added in my answer an image that will explain really clearly the lifecycle. about launch mode, just read the doc and it will explain a lot. for any question ask freely

Comment: @Peir Giorgio Misley, Thank you... :-)

Comment: welcome :) if you think that the answer solved your problem, remember to check it as the solution so it can help other programmers with your same doubt :)

Answer (score 0):

When you call finish() it will not remain in backstack

Answer (score 0):

No ActivityA will not remain in Stack.